# $(window).resize function causes div to disappear

Tags: jquery, firefox, position, window-resize

In my design I would like to keep a the buttons in sight when re-sizing the browser (firefox). The buttons are in a relative DIV and when the height is too small it sets the DIV to absolute. But on re-sizing the window the DIV flickers and disappears/appears randomly.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            body {
                /*overflow: hidden;*/
                border:  2px dotted lightblue;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                right:  0;
                bottom:  0;
                left:  0;
                margin:  0;
                padding:  0;
            }
            .maxheight {
                max-height:  100%;
                /*overflow:  hidden;*/
            }
            .scrollable {
                overflow:  auto;
                height:  100%;
                background-color:  yellow;
                border:  1px solid black;
                position: relative;
                max-height:  100%;
                bottom:  0px;
            }
            .buttons {
                background-color: red;
                border:  1px solid black;
                position: relative;
                bottom:  0px;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(window).resize(function () {
                var pageHeight = $("#page").height();
                var buttons = $(".buttons");
                var elementHeight = $(buttons).height()
                var elementTop = $(buttons).position().top;
                var total = pageHeight - (elementHeight + elementTop);
                if (pageHeight - (elementHeight + elementTop) < 0) {
                    $(buttons).css({
                        'position': 'absolute',
                        'width': $(".scrollable").width()
                    });
                } else {
                    $(buttons).css({
                        'position': 'relative',
                        'width': $(".scrollable").width()
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="page">
        <div class="maxheight">
            <h2>title</h2>
            <div class="scrollable">
                This is content.<br />
                This is content.<br />
                This is content.<br />
                This is content.<br />
                This is content.<br />
                This is content.<br />
                This is content.<br />
                This is content.<br />
                This is content.<br />
                This is content.<br />
                This is content.<br />
                This is content.<br />
                This is content.
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <button type="button" value="test">test</button>
                <button type="button" value="test">test</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GxDES/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GxDES/1/)

I think part of the problem is not setting the `top` for absolute and relative in the jquery. When it switches to absolute, it doesn't know where to position itself, so it could be different depending on the browser.

```
if (pageHeight - (elementHeight + elementTop) < 0) {
    $(buttons).css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': elementTop + 'px',  //ADDED THIS LINE
            'width': $(".scrollable").width()
    });
} else {
    $(buttons).css({
        'position': 'relative',
        'top': '0px',  //ADDED THIS LINE
            'width': $(".scrollable").width()
    });
}
```

I also added a `height` to your css `.buttons` to make the red background consistent and remain.

Hope that helps.

EDIT:

I change one thing.  Position the `.buttons` right below the `.scrollable`.  Works a little better this way.  http://jsfiddle.net/GxDES/2/

```
var pos = $('div.scrollable').position().top + $('div.scrollable').height();
'top': pos + 'px',  //CHANGED THIS LINE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat effective solution that simplifies the call to:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('.buttons').fixToBottom().css('width', $('.scrollable').width());
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XVNQk/